# sum of elements in n lists python

Tags: python

Hello friends for now I'm trying to make the soma of 2 lists with the same amount of element, but I do not want to use the Zip method I want to know why this error occurs to me and how to solve it:

```
l1 =[2,5,8]
l2 = [4,8,0]

for i in l1:
  for j in l2:
   print l1[i] + l2[j]
```

and I get the following error:

```
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I do not understand why I get this error, and I would like to know how I can solve if there are n quantities of lists and each of them does not have the same sizes of elements

Comment: `i` is an *element* in `l1`, not an *index*, and `j` the same for `l2`. `l1[2]` works fine, but I'd actually expect the error *before* reaching `6` as `l2[4]` is also an `IndexError`.

Comment: The code posted can't produce the `6` shown in the output. It'll just throw the `IndexError` straight at the start.

Comment: Plus if you want to sum the numbers element wise (eg you want `[6, 13, 8]` as output) - you don't want to be using a nested for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this be something you are looking for?

```
l1 =[2,5,8]
l2 =[4,8,0]

sums = [] # initialize the list of sums.
minlen = min(len(l1), len(l2))

for i in range(minlen): 
    sums.append(l1[i] + l2[i])

print(sums)
```

> [6, 13, 8]

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and `enumerate`

```
l3 = [l1[idx] + l2[idx] for idx, item in enumerate(l1)]
```

> ```
> ~/python/stackoverflow/9.23$ python3.7 dicta.py
> [6, 13, 8]
> ```

Expanded loop:

```
l3 = []
for idx, item in enumerate(l1):
    l3.append(l1[idx] + l2[idx])
```

Comment: `item` is unused

Comment: @Bazingaa   I know this , just using it for index, didn't want same answer as you, but also I was told before using `(range(len))` is bad practice even though I agree here it makes much sense

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension. I assume both lists are equal in length

```
l1 =[2,5,8]
l2 = [4,8,0]
sum_list = [l1[i] + l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))]
print (sum_list)
> [6, 13, 8]
```

Comment: `l3 = [l1[i] + l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))]` just as I was posting, I wasn't sure if there was a better parameter we could implent instead of `range(len)`

Comment: went with enumerate

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is because you are mixing up two ways of iterating through lists.

You can either do

```
l1 =[2,5,8]
l2 = [4,8,0]

for i in l1:
  for j in l2:
   print i + j
```

Or

```
l1 =[2,5,8]
l2 = [4,8,0]

for i in range(len(l1)):
  for j in range(len(l2)):
   print l1[i] + l2[j]
```

The problem you are having is that using your method of iterating through a list - `for i in l1` - is that `i` will equal the first element in `l1`, then the second, etc.
That means you were trying to acess the 2nd, then the 5th and then the 8th index of `l1`.

`for i in range(len(l1))` will `l1[i]` will equal the element of `l1`, then the second and so on until it reaches the end of the list.